# MbUnit tests pass when run directly from visual studio, but fails when run via command line

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, testing, mbunit, gallio

I've been using MbUnit for unit testing for a while, along with Nhibernate and Sqlite.

I am now trying to setup a CI server with Jenkins - I have successfully managed to configure Jenkins to pull the code from github and compile it using MSBuild everytime anyone pushes to github. Finally I want to run tests on the code on each successful build.

The tests all **run successfully when run from within Visual Studio** without any problem whatsoever, I can run each test individually or the whole project and they all run OK. However when I call Gallio.Echo.exe from command line all the tests that have to do with Sqlite fails.

This is what I've been doing to run the test from command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Gallio\bin\Gallio.Echo.exe" /report-type:Html /verbosity:quiet "D:\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug\*.Tests.dll"
```

<sup>(ps: There seems to be absolutely no documentation about gallio tools - have I been looking in all the wrong palces? I want to find more about the command line arguments that I can pass)</sup>

The tests fail with this:

```
   Gallio Echo - Version 3.3 build 454
   Get the latest version at http://www.gallio.org/

   Initializing the runtime and loading plugins.
   Verifying test files.
   Initializing the test runner.
   Running the tests.
   [failed] Fixture MyProject.Tests/VerificationTests
   Set Up
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

    ---> NHibernate.HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4. 
    ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
    ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   HResult: -2147024809
      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
      at NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName)
      at NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver..ctor()
      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I've [tried a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423875/363674) few [solutions mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493910/363674) around on SO but haven't been able to solve it. The only close thing was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/944645/363674) but I am not sure what the user means by adding to config files.

Anyone has any idea why the tests fail from command line but are okay when run from within VS please?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because the sqlite.dll is not in the bin path but on the pc with VS in the GAC -> running fine, on the PC with Jenkins it is not in GAC -> failing#

Comment: @Firo the sqlite.data.dll is actually present in the bin folder, plus enabled to download from nuget too.. and I can see the dll right in the bin too so that's not the issue I think.

Comment: did you double check that the bin folder **containing the tests-dll** contains the sqlite dll?

Comment: @Firo - yup, the test/bin/ does contain all the files it needs. From what I can make out, the error is not that it can't find the file, rather that it can't load the right driver outside visual studio.

Comment: ReflectionBasedDriver tries to load the dll directly and if not present uses the DbProviderFactories. the exception tells you that both failed. Maybe the dll SQLite20Driver expects and the driver present are not compatible